# How to deploy multiple app servers from different branches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, web-deployment, rubber

I have a RoR app running on 2 app/web servers using nginx/unicorn. The site is deployed using [Rubber](https://github.com/rubber/rubber) from the "master" branch of our repo. Life is good!

Some of the new customers we are working with require their data and files to be kept on separate servers. We are planning on having separate boxes for each of these customers. The sites for these customers will be available at customerX.site.com and the code for these apps will be the same as the code in the "master" branch except for a couple of images and the database.yml file.

So my question is, is there a way to set the git branch that should be used to pull the code based on the role of the box or any alternative to easily manage this multi-app deployment process?

Comment: you want to deploy with one command in several servers? Or a flexible command that allows you to choose a branch each time you deploy?

Comment: I would like to have the ability to deploy to all the servers at once or FILTER by role but at this point I will take anything as a starting point. I am also open to some other deployment solution if it helps.